# choosing between process and thread, and inter-process(thread) communication

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, network-programming

I want to write a simple UDP server program which use recvfrom() to receive packet
for each received packet, the program will process it
my original source codes are like:

```
for(;;){
n = recvfrom(sockfd, mesg, 10000, 0 ptr_sockaddr, &len);
process(mesg);
}
```

but in this way, if the `process()` function takes a bit long time, it will influence the `recvfrom()`. so I need to create a new process or new thread,

1. which one is better for this scenario? thread or process? why?
2. how to deal with the inter-process or inter-thread communication, I
   mean I need to deliver the character string `mesg` to the new
   process(or thread). And if the packet receiption is much faster than
   the processing, what kind buffering method should I use?

if some source code snippets can be provided, that's better!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having one thread that loops around `recvfrom`. When it receives a datagram, have it put that datagram on a queue. You can then have a pool of threads that pull datagrams from the queue and process them.

The usual solution is to have a mutex and a condition variable that protects the queue. Adding an item to the queue works like this:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Add the item to the queue.
3. Signal the condition variable.
4. Release the mutex.

And the threads in the pool do this:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. If there's an item in the queue, skip to step 5.
3. Block on the condition variable releasing the mutex.
4. Go to step 2.
5. Remove the item from the queue.
6. Release the mutex.
7. Process the item we removed from the queue.
8. Go to step 1.

You may want to prevent the queue from growing indefinitely though. It's always possible you might receive datagrams faster than you can process them and allowing the queue's memory usage to just keep growing is not a good idea.

Comment: are there any similar source code exmaples? I'm not familiar with multi-threading at the moment, but I want to finish the task asap

Comment: @user1944267: If you're in a hurry, I wouldn't suggest making this your first foray into multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Using thread is more simple because threads could see the memory of its paraent process. so it could access to variables and to memory, read them and change them.

Using process will not allow you to access in write directly to the parent process memory you have to use other ways to change variable and memory of parent process like shared memory (mmap)

Comment: but how to buffer the `mesg`, like put them in a queue, waiting for processing?

Comment: this could another question try some code and then go back for a new question if you are locked in some points

Answer (score 0):

Declare some struct to contain the data.  Malloc one.  Read in a message. Queue off the *struct and immediately malloc, (or depool), another one for the next message.  Free, or repool, the *struct after handling in the consumer.

You can do flow control by either:

1) Using a bounded blocking queue, freeing the *struct at the consumer end after handling.

2) Using two unbounded blocking queues - one prefilled with *struct to act as a pool, the other to communicate between the threads. When the recvFrom thread needs a *struct, pop it from the pool. When the consumer has handled a *struct, push it back onto the pool.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He asked whether to use processes or threads.

Answer (score 0):

if the function process() is not returning anything to the parent it's much easier to create a process per message. all you need to do is add if (fork()<=0) return; in the beginning of process() and you don't need to worry about overwriting mesg and ptr_sockaddr.

Answer (score 0):

Process. Then a programming error will tear down a single connection and not the entire server.

For communication you can establish a shared memory region before the fork() between the father and all child processes and sync. using mutex/semaphores.